# Is it possible to set up project-wide VM arguments in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm-arguments

I'm using Eclipse, and I need to pass a set of VM arguments to my run configurations. I know how to do it individually using "Run/Debug Settings". And I know how to do it systemwide using Window/Preferences/Java/Installed JREs.

My problem is that I have multiple projects that require different VM arguments. Also, within each project, I have a number of classes to run, so if I go with "Run/Debug Settings" route, duplicating run configurations would be tedious. Even more tedious would be changing individual values inside all of these configurations when I have to make such change.

Is there any way to maintain project-specific run configurations in Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Window → Preferences → Java → Installed JREs

**First Configuration:**

```
Default VM Arguments: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 

JRE Home: JRE1-PorojectType (You can name it anything)
```

**Second Configuration:**

```
Default VM Arguments: -XX:HeapDumpPath=${DOMAIN_HOME}/logs/mps"

JRE Home: JRE2-PorojectType (You can name it anything)
```

Associate the configured JRE to relevant project, then project will have the default configured VM arguments.

Comment: Hmm , create custom JRE entries for projects... that seems to be a good idea, let me try.

Comment: Thank you, fabfas, that worked! It only took me a little while to figure out how to associate an existing project with a different JRE (Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Libraries), but once I set everything up, every new run configuration successfully inherits my custom JRE with all of its VM settings.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. I edited my answer with what's probably a better long term solution. Sounds like you should start looking into external build tools instead of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The question wasn't clear initially, but the asker is looking for a way to specify VM arguments for unit tests.

In the case that you need specific VM arguments, you shouldn't rely on Eclipse and prefer a build tool like Maven or Gradle. If your workspace is corrupted (It happens occasionally, for whatever reason) your configurations are all gone.

Using Maven Surefire, you can specify VM arguments to run when executing unit tests on a per-project basis. Not only that, this is IDE agnostic.

You could define it this way in your pom.xml, for example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

--
Run configurations are already project specific. Right click the project, select `Run As`, then `Run Configurations` at the bottom of the menu. You specify which project they apply to when creating them:

[image: Run Configuration]

You can specify VM arguments in the Arguments tab, and you can duplicate run configurations by right clicking them and selecting duplicate.

Comment: Yes, configurations are project-specific, but not project-wide - there is no inheritance. I can create "New_configuration", but then I have to duplicate it for every class that I run. Say, I have 50 classes, and after the first pass, I need to change one of the arguments for _all_ of them.

Comment: It's not clear what the difference between project specific and project wide is. You should have a single entry point to your application... Why do you need a configuration for every class in your project?

Comment: @Christopher Schneider there is no reason why a project should only have one public static void main class. But as far as I know, what OP is asking is not possible. There are two levels: default jre arguments, and run configurations. Maybe what you could do is add a JRE with the jvm arguments for that project, and use that jre for the project run targets.

Comment: My project is actually a collection of tests, and the code that being tested relies on VM arguments. I need a convenient way to change VM setting for all of the tests at once.